# Optional Parameters in Class Constructors in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, constructor

Is there a way to mitigate the order of optional parameters in TypeScript? I currently have the class

```
export default class Area {
    private name: string;
    private description: string;
    private item?: Item;
    private hazard?: Hazard;

    constructor(name: string, description: string, item?: Item, hazard?: Hazard) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.item = item;
        this.hazard = hazard;
    }
}
```

For this Area class, I required the `name` and `string` parameters but not the `item` or `hazard` parameters. I tried instantiating an Area object in the following ways:

```
let item = new Item(); // had required parameters, but not important for now
let hazard = new Hazard(); // had required parameters, but not important for now

let area = new Area("test", "test"); // works as expected
let area1 = new Area("test", "test", item); // works as expected
let area2 = new Area("test", "test", hazard); // DOES NOT WORK as expected
let area3 = new Area("test", "test", item, hazard); // works as expected
```

Even though `hazard` and `item` are optional, if I want to omit `item`, I need to pass in `undefined` for the third parameter. Is there anyway to mitigate or forego this behavior, where we can pass in a third argument that matches any of the optional parameters?

Comment: No this is not possible in javascript/typescript. What you can do is change constructor to accept object like `{ name: string, description: string,  item?: Item, hazard?: Hazard }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type-checking done by Typescript exists *only* in Typescript- it doesn't exist in the compiled Javascript, so if that was allowed, there wouldn't be any way for Javascript to determine which argument you're actually trying to pass.

Instead, pass an optional *object* which may have the `item` or `hazard` properties:

```
class Item{}
class Hazard{}

export default class Area {
    private name: string;
    private description: string;
    private item?: Item;
    private hazard?: Hazard;

    constructor(
      name: string,
      description: string,
      obj: { item?: Item, hazard?: Hazard } = {}
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        if (obj.item) this.item = obj.item;
        if (obj.hazard) this.hazard = obj.hazard;
    }
}

const item = new Item();
const hazard = new Hazard();

const area = new Area("test", "test"); 
const area1 = new Area("test", "test", { item });
const area2 = new Area("test", "test", { hazard });
const area3 = new Area("test", "test", { item, hazard });
```

Comment: For more context, converting named parameters to structured parameters is a common pattern in typescript. It's common enough that there's a language level refactor tool for it - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23552